# Apollo GraphQL mutation results not updating with PostgreSQL but works with SQLite

Tags: javascript, postgresql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

Why do I get the updated data from my update resolver with SQLite but not postgress? Also I'm using Sequelize for the ORM if that matters.

Just general qestion about Apollo and databases. Basically I have an update user resolver that updates some fields on a user and returns back the user. When using SQLite the returned data is the proper updated user. However when I switch to postgres the data is always 1 update behind? So when I initially update the user when using postgres nothing changes, but the next time I update it I get the data from the previous update and so on. I'm just confused because I have changed no code, just the database it uses. Does Apollo behave differently with different databases or does postgress behave differently from sqlite?

```js
// model

"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
      lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
      userType: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  );

  User.associate = function(models) {
  };
```

```js
// typeDef

  type User {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    userType: String
    createdAt: String
    updatedAt: String
  }
```

```js
// resolver

    async updateUser(
      root,
      {
        id,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        userType,
      },
      { models }
    ) {
      models.User.update(
        {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          userType: userType,
        },
        {
          where: { id: id }
        }
      );
      return models.User.findByPk(id);
    },
```

```
//query

mutation {
  updateEmployee(
    id: 1
    firstName: "testName"
    lastName: "testUpdate"
    employeeID: "12345"
  ){
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    employeeID
    createdAt
    updatedAt
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not awaiting the `update` call, so `findByPk` returns the user before the `update` call has a chance to complete.

```
await models.User.update(  // <-- here
  {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    userType: userType,
  },
  {
    where: { id: id }
  }
);
return models.User.findByPk(id);
```

FWIW, if you're using Postgres, you can use a single call by providing a `returning` option:

```
const [_, user] = await models.User.update(
  {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    userType: userType,
  },
  {
    where: { id: id },
    returning: true,
  }
);
return user;
```